# How to allow content area to be expandable to right but not pop under sidebar?

Tags: css, css-float

I often run in the following problem, I have a web page with the following divs:

- header
- sidebar
- content
- footer

sidebar and content are both float left with a break afterwards.

**I want content to expand to the right edge of the browser, no matter how wide or narrow the browser width.**

However, no matter what I try, I am face with two choices:

- content must be a fixed width
- content is not a fixed with (no width property) but resizing the browser pops the content down under the sidebar

The site I'm working on has many more divs than these four so it's hard to post CSS code that is not convoluted, but **does anyone have a general strategy to enable content to expand out to the browser's right edge while never popping under sidebar if browser width is made too small?**

My current solution is: table.

[image]

## Addendum 1

Thanks Hristo, your solution works except that sidebar and content can't have fixed heights, which causes the footer to appear in the middle. Since you aren't using floats, how do you make the footer come after both of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/ABFG2/10/

---

Check out the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/ABFG2/2/

Let me know if you have any questions. I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: Thanks, your solution works on my page, except for the fact that I can't have fixed heights for sidebar and content otherwise the footer overlays on top of them in the middle, how can I get the footer to come after the sidebar/content (see screenshot added in my answer).

Comment: @Edward... do you mind posting the link to jsfiddle with your updated code and I'll take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set a `margin-left` to the #content and `position:absolute` to the #sidebar.

For example:

```
<div id=wrap>
  <div id=content>
    ...
  </div>
  <div> id=sidebar>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and some css

```
  * { 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0;
  }
  #content {
      margin-left: 200px;
      background: green;
  }
  #sidebar {
      width: 200px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: pink;
  }
```

and the example:
http://jsbin.com/umomuk
This is the same solution that google uses on their search result pages.

Answer (score 1):

On solution will be to use the minimum width:

```
.containerDiv {
  min-width: 600px;
}
```

if the div is greater than 600px it will just expand, and if the window is resized to a lower value the minimum width will be 600px. However, some versions of IE doesn't support this property, a different solution will have to be implemented for IE.

This link suggest a hack, but i have not tested that personally.

[CSS play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/minwidth.html)

Comment: on firefox put mid-width: 600px / width:1000px on the content area but it still pops under, I also tried putting a 1000px on the wrapper which wraps sidebar and content but content still pops under, what am I missing here?

Comment: @Edward: Oh it's min-width not mid-width. and don't set both width and min-width, use only one of them.